# Transfer image file to server in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, web-services

I'm working on my iOS app in which i want to send image file to server.

How can i send image file file in byte format.

Please give your valuable suggestions.

Comment: `byte` is not actually an image format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below given function

```
   -(NSString *)getStringFromImage:(UIImage *)image{
        if(image){
            NSData *dataObj = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
            //[appDelegate showAlert:@"Data Size" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Data length = %lu",(unsigned long)dataObj.length]];
            return [dataObj base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
        } else {
            return @"";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Convert ur image in to NSData and use base64 encoding and add it to jsonarray**

```
NSDictionary *newDatasetInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourimage, 1) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0], @"image", nil];

if([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:newDatasetInfo]){


//convert object to data
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:newDatasetInfo options:kNilOptions error:nil];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your url"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];


NSURLSessionConfiguration *config=[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

NSURLSession *session=[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

NSURLSessionDataTask *task=[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    if(response){
        NSString *resp = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Echo %@",resp);


        });


    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Timeout");



        });

    }



}];
[task resume];

}
```

**Later on server(php) side decode the base 64 and u can save it**

```
 <?php
$string =  @file_get_contents('php://input');
 $json = json_decode($string, true);


    $file = 'uploads/filename';
    $file_info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
    // Extract the mime type
    $mime_type = $file_info->buffer($json['image']);
    file_put_contents($file, base64_decode($json['image']));
    echo "sucess saving image";
exit;
?>
```